# Whole item distribution by ratio

Tags: java, python, math, pseudocode

### The goal:

Say I have X workers in a fruit plantation. At the plantation they're growing apples, pears and grapes.

At the end of the day, the foreman grades each workers with a ratio. The total of all ratio's is 100. The ratio is there to determine how to distribute the fruit amongst the workers at the end of the day.

How do I distribute the fruit amongst all workers so that they each get their fair share (within a certain randomness to account for integer division). Only whole fruits are divided, so integer results. And all fruits must be given out.

I'm doing this with about 20 workers, so right now the ratio is in neighbourhood of 0.05 per worker.

### What I've tried (pseudo-code):

```
for each worker:
  if applesGiven < appleStock:
    worker.give(ratio * applestock);
  if pearsGiven < pearStock:
    worker.give(ratio * pearStock);
  if grapesGiven < grapeStock:
    worker.give(ratio * grapeStock);
```

I would let the exact numer of [fruit] they where given be determined by a `boolean Roundup` that was initialized with a random boolean and switched after every fruit that was processed.

### What I've tried (full-code):

```
public void balance() {
        boolean roundUp = random.nextBoolean();
        for (Employee e : employees) {
            double ratio = e.getRatio();
            if (applePlanned < appleNeeded) {
                int apple;
                if (roundUp) {
                    apple = (int) Math.ceil(ratio * appleNeeded);
                } else {
                    apple = (int) Math.floor(ratio * appleNeeded);
                }
                e.setrapple(apple);
                applePlanned += apple;
                roundUp = !roundUp;
            }

            if (pearPlanned < pearNeeded) {
                int pear;
                if (roundUp) {
                    pear = (int) Math.ceil(ratio * pearNeeded);
                } else {
                    pear = (int) Math.floor(ratio * pearNeeded);
                }
                e.setrpear(pear);
                pearPlanned += pear;
                roundUp = !roundUp;
            }

            if (grapePlanned < grapeNeeded) {
                int grape;
                if (roundUp) {
                    grape = (int) Math.ceil(ratio * grapeNeeded);
                } else {
                    grape = (int) Math.floor(ratio * grapeNeeded);
                }
                e.setrgrape(grape);
                grapePlanned += grape;
                roundUp = !roundUp;
            }
}
```

### Problems I ran into:

- Only about 3/4 of all items are distributed
- When I have an even number of fruit, the boolean gets the same value at the start of each new person.

**Thank you for looking into this!**

**Answers in java, python or pseudo-code please, that's what I can read.**

Comment: Without seeing the exact code, it's impossible to tell why you're having the specific problems you're having.  Off the top of my head, the way I'd do it is to round down all the time, but keep track of the  total rounding error for each worker (which will be a number in the interval [0,3) ).  Then for the fruit that's left over, for every worker whose rounding error is in [2,3), give them two random fruits, and if it's in [1,2), give them one random fruit.  That will leave every worker's error in the range [0,1); now just give out random fruit starting with the worker with the largest error.

Comment: I have added the code per your request. Why is the rounding error in that interval?

Comment: What I mean is this: If you figure out how many apples you want to give, and you round it down, the difference ("error", as I called it) is between 0 and 1.  Since you do this for three fruits, the total of the three errors will be from 0 to 3.  It's hard to explain in a short comment but I didn't feel it was good enough to post as an answer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  I can't figure out why only 3/4 of the items would be distributed; I tried your code and that doesn't happen.  Check to make sure the employee ratios add up to 1.0.  As for the second issue: do you mean an even number of different *kinds* of fruit?  (Instead of 3, like you've shown us.)  That would be because you perform `roundUp = !roundUp` an even number of times; the solution would be to add a second boolean `roundUpStart` that gets complemented (`roundUpStart = !roundUpStart`) only once per employee, and initialize `roundUp` to that for each employee.

Comment: Hmmm, that certainly solves issue 2. I'll look into external factors why I'm not handing out all the fruit and the code is doing it for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use double math, round down, then randomly hand out the remaining fruit weighted based on ratio. Note, you can make this a lot less ugly with object orientation and loops, but this is a start.

```
public void distribute(int apple, int pear, int grape) {
    double total = apple + pear + grape;
    double appleRatio = apple/total;
    double pearRatio = pear/total;
    double grapeRatio = grape/total;

    // apple worker
    int appleWorkerApple = (int) (appleRatio*apple);
    int appleWorkerPear = (int) (appleRatio*pear);
    int appleWorkerGrape = (int) (appleRatio*grape);

    // pear worker
    int pearWorkerApple = (int) (pearRatio*apple);
    int pearWorkerPear = (int) (pearRatio*pear);
    int pearWorkerGrape = (int) (pearRatio*grape);

    // grape worker
    int grapeWorkerApple = (int) (grapeRatio*apple);
    int grapeWorkerPear = (int) (grapeRatio*pear);
    int grapeWorkerGrape = (int) (grapeRatio*grape);

    int appleRemain = apple - appleWorkerApple - pearWorkerApple - grapeWorkerApple;
    int pearRemain = pear - appleWorkerApple - pearWorkerApple - grapeWorkerApple;
    int grapeRemain = grape - appleWorkerApple - pearWorkerApple - grapeWorkerApple;

    Random r = new Random();
    while(appleRemain > 0 && pearRemain > 0 && grapeRemain > 0) {
        double target = r.nextDouble();
        switch(r.nextInt(3)) {
        case 0:
            if(appleRemain > 0) {
                appleRemain--
                if(target < appleRatio)
                    appleWorkerApple++;
                else if (target < appleRatio + grapeRatio)
                    pearWorkerApple++;
                else
                    grapeWorkerApple++;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(grapeRemain > 0)
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's a great start. I'm just missing the point of the apple to fruit ratio. Why are you using that? The ratio is on the worker, say the foreman has 20 workers, and he assigns each of them a percentage of the yield. Totalling up to 100%.

Comment: @Difusio If the foreman grades the workers at the end of the day, then you need to figure out what the grade is going to be, right? Anyway, when I made this answer I thought you had exactly three workers, one for each plant. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Yeah I have X workers who do all the work together, so no specific tasks, they just get a grade or share of the yield for the day. Right now I went with:
- Shuffle the list
- Sort by ratio
- Hand out fruit top to bottom, if there is anything left start from the top again.
- For the next fruit start at step 1 again.

But this feels a bit biased towards them with higher ratio.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly useful 'cause I've overused Numpy but I'll share since it's relevant

```
import numpy
import random

# apple, bannana, grapes, guava, melon, pear
fruits = numpy.array([100, 150, 175, 200, 230, 247])

# Bill, Bob, Dan, Fred, Joe
ratios = numpy.array([21, 7, 32, 13, 27])

# Original fruit amount for each worker: 0
worker_fruits = numpy.zeros((5, 6), dtype=int)
worker_lucky  = numpy.zeros((5, 6), dtype=float)

# For each worker with his ratio
for worker, lucky, ratio in zip(worker_fruits, worker_lucky, ratios):
    # Give him fruits, storing partials as weighting
    to_give = (ratio * fruits) / 100
    lucky  += to_give % 1
    worker += to_give

# Calculate how much we have left over
spares = fruits - worker_fruits.sum(axis=0)

# Share it out in a weighted distribution
for fruit, lucky, numspare in zip(worker_fruits.transpose(), worker_lucky.transpose(), spares):
    if numspare:
        indexes = numpy.arange(len(fruit))
        add_to = numpy.random.choice(indexes, replace=False, size=numspare, p=lucky/numspare)
        fruit[add_to] += 1

# Our results!
worker_fruits
#>>> array([[21, 31, 36, 42, 49, 51],
#>>>        [ 7, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18],
#>>>        [32, 48, 56, 64, 74, 79],
#>>>        [13, 19, 23, 26, 29, 32],
#>>>        [27, 41, 48, 54, 62, 67]])

# Proof it's perfectly shared
fruits - worker_fruits.sum(axis=0)
#>>> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Oh boy, thanks, now let me delve into numpy to see how to convert this to Java. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: Just a warning: `numpy.random.choice(indexes, replace=False, size=numspare, p=lucky/numspare)` hides a *lot* of complexity. I suggest going up from durron597's rather than down from mine.